# For all positive integers $m$ and $n$ prove the inequality $ |n\sqrt{n^2+1}-m|\geqslant \sqrt{2}-1$

Tags: inequality

> For all positive integers $m$ and $n$ prove the inequality
> $$
> |n\sqrt{n^2+1}-m|\geqslant \sqrt{2}-1.
> $$

---

If $n>m$, and $n,m$ are natural numbers, then we have to show $n \sqrt{n^2+1}-m \geqslant \sqrt{2}-1$. Now, $$\begin{array}{l} 
n-1 \geqslant m \\
\Rightarrow n \sqrt{n^2+1}-m \geqslant n \sqrt{n^2+1}-n+1
\end{array}$$. Let $f(n)=n \sqrt{n^2+1}-n+1$. $f(1)= √2>√2-1$. $f^{\prime}(n)=\frac{2 n^2+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}-1>0$ So, $f(n)$ is increasing. Hence, $n \sqrt{n^2+1}-m > \sqrt{2}-1$. Now this was the case for $n>m$. I can prove this for $n=m$ aswell, but I'm stuck at showing this would be true for $m>n$. Can someone please provide me hints so that I can proceed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that you'd likely want to consider the case when $ n \sqrt{n^2 + 1 } \approx m$, or that $ m \approx n^2$. So the cases that you've looked at don't seem that helpful.

Comment: You can show that if $m = n^2$ the difference is positive. And if $m = n^2 +1$ the difference is negative. So one must consider these two cases, and determine the maximal magnitude of the difference as a function of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

(Prove the hints yourself. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried. The hidden parts correspond to how we're using the hints, so I encourage you to think about their implications before reading further. IE Use the hints as actual hints. )

**Hint 1:** Show that $ 0 < n \sqrt{ n^2 + 1} - n^2  < \frac{1}{2}$.

> For $ m \neq n^2$, then $| n \sqrt{ n^2 + 1 } - m | \geq \frac{1}{2} > \sqrt{2} - 1$.
>  Hence, $|n\sqrt{n^2+1} - m|$ is minimized when $ m = n^2$.

**Hint 2:** Show that $ n\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n^2 \geq \sqrt{2} - 1$.
This can be done easily through calculus, or by repeated squaring.

**Alternate approach, Hint 2:**  $n^2(n^2 + 1 ) - (n^2)^2 = n^2$.

> Since $ |n \sqrt{n^2 +1 } + n^2 | \leq 2n^2 + 1$, so $|n \sqrt{n^2 + 1 } - n^2 | \geq \frac{ n^2 } { 2n^2 + 1} $.
>  So $ |n \sqrt{n^2 + 1 } - n^2 | > \sqrt{2} -1$ for $ n \geq 2$.

> Finally, show that for $n = 1$, $ |n \sqrt{n^2 + 1 } - n^2 | \geq \sqrt{2} -1$.
>  Hence we are done.

Comment: I don't understand why are we considering $m$ to be $n^2$ at the first place?

Comment: See the updated corollary to hint 1. Do you understand why the LHS is minimized when $m = n^2$? Alternatively, if $m \neq n^2$, can you show that  $ | n\sqrt{n^2+1} - m| > 0.5$?

Answer (score 0):

the series, with $0 < x < 1,$  for $ \sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8}  + smaller \; \; $  suggests simply getting bounds on $ \sqrt{n^4 + n^2}.$   We may simply try things  similar to the series. Indeed, with $n \geq 1,$
$$  \left( n^2 + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 = n^4 + n^2 + \frac{1}{4}  > n^4 + n^2  $$
while
$$  \left( n^2 + \frac{1}{2} -  \frac{1}{8n^2}  \right)^2 =  n^2 + \frac{1}{2} -  \frac{1}{8n^2} +  \frac{1}{64n^4} < n^4 + n^2  $$  Which is to say

$$  n^2 + \frac{1}{2} -  \frac{1}{8n^2}  \; < \; \sqrt{n^4 + n^2}  \; < \;  n^2 + \frac{1}{2}          $$

Once $ n \geq 2$   we find $  n^2 + \frac{1}{2} -  \frac{1}{32} =  n^2 + \frac{15}{32}   \; < \; \sqrt{n^4 + n^2}  \; < \;  n^2 + \frac{1}{2}          $